# Why can't I connect to this Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric, ports, windows-firewall

I'm blocked by an error when connecting to a remote service fabric cluster running on premise (**not** on Azure) using the [`Connect-ServiceFabricCluster`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125938.aspx) PowerShell command for a network-connected virtual machine:

```
WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
False
WARNING: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.1.102:19000
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.
At Install.ps1:3 char:1
+ Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "FABRICTESTSRV:19000" -WindowsCred ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

The command is:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "FABRICTESTSRV:19000" -WindowsCredential:$True
```

Why isn't it working?

Here is what I have tried:

- I have tried turning Windows Firewall off entirely. No luck there.
- Connecting locally to the cluster while inside of the virtual machine works just fine: `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster "localhost:19000"`
- This is not a DNS issue. I can ping the FQDN of the machine just fine.

**Note**: This is not an Azure hosted Virtual Machine. This is simply a network-connected virtual machine running Service Fabric Core, vanilla Windows 8.1 x64 fully up to date.

**Edit**: `Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest` reads as follows:

```
<ClusterManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="ComputerName-Local-Cluster" Version=
"1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <NodeTypes>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType0">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19000" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19001" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19002" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19080" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19081" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19006" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="30001" EndPort="31000" />
      </Endpoints>
    </NodeType>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType1">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19010" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19011" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19012" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19082" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19083" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19016" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="31001" EndPort="32000" />
      </Endpoints>
    </NodeType>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType2">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19020" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19021" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19022" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19084" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19085" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19026" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="32001" EndPort="33000" />
      </Endpoints>
    </NodeType>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType3">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19030" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19031" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19032" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19086" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19087" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19036" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="33001" EndPort="34000" />
      </Endpoints>
    </NodeType>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType4">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19040" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19041" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19042" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19088" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19089" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19046" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="34001" EndPort="35000" />
      </Endpoints>
    </NodeType>
  </NodeTypes>
  <Infrastructure>
    <WindowsServer IsScaleMin="true">
      <NodeList>
        <Node NodeName="_Node_0" IPAddressOrFQDN="localhost" IsSeedNode="true" NodeTypeRef="NodeType0" FaultDomain="fd:/0" UpgradeDomain="0" />
        <Node NodeName="_Node_1" IPAddressOrFQDN="localhost" IsSeedNode="true" NodeTypeRef="NodeType1" FaultDomain="fd:/1" UpgradeDomain="1" />
        <Node NodeName="_Node_2" IPAddressOrFQDN="localhost" IsSeedNode="true" NodeTypeRef="NodeType2" FaultDomain="fd:/2" UpgradeDomain="2" />
        <Node NodeName="_Node_3" IPAddressOrFQDN="localhost" NodeTypeRef="NodeType3" FaultDomain="fd:/3" UpgradeDomain="3" />
        <Node NodeName="_Node_4" IPAddressOrFQDN="localhost" NodeTypeRef="NodeType4" FaultDomain="fd:/4" UpgradeDomain="4" />
      </NodeList>
    </WindowsServer>
  </Infrastructure>
  <FabricSettings>
    <Section Name="Security">
      <Parameter Name="ClusterCredentialType" Value="None" />
      <Parameter Name="ServerAuthCredentialType" Value="None" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="FailoverManager">
      <Parameter Name="ExpectedClusterSize" Value="4" />
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="ReconfigurationTimeLimit" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="BuildReplicaTimeLimit" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="CreateInstanceTimeLimit" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="PlacementTimeLimit" Value="20" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ReconfigurationAgent">
      <Parameter Name="ServiceApiHealthDuration" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="ServiceReconfigurationApiHealthDuration" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="LocalHealthReportingTimerInterval" Value="5" />
      <Parameter Name="IsDeactivationInfoEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="RAUpgradeProgressCheckInterval" Value="3" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ClusterManager">
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="UpgradeStatusPollInterval" Value="5" />
      <Parameter Name="UpgradeHealthCheckInterval" Value="5" />
      <Parameter Name="FabricUpgradeHealthCheckInterval" Value="5" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="NamingService">
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Management">
      <Parameter Name="ImageStoreConnectionString" Value="file:C:\SfDevCluster\Data\ImageStoreShare" />
      <Parameter Name="ImageCachingEnabled" Value="false" />
      <Parameter Name="EnableDeploymentAtDataRoot" Value="true" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Hosting">
      <Parameter Name="EndpointProviderEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="RunAsPolicyEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="DeactivationScanInterval" Value="60" />
      <Parameter Name="DeactivationGraceInterval" Value="10" />
      <Parameter Name="EnableProcessDebugging" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="ServiceTypeRegistrationTimeout" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="CacheCleanupScanInterval" Value="300" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="HttpGateway">
      <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="PlacementAndLoadBalancing">
      <Parameter Name="MinLoadBalancingInterval" Value="300" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Federation">
      <Parameter Name="NodeIdGeneratorVersion" Value="V4" />
      <Parameter Name="UnresponsiveDuration" Value="0" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ApplicationGateway/Http">
      <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="FaultAnalysisService">
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Trace/Etw">
      <Parameter Name="Level" Value="4" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Diagnostics">
      <Parameter Name="ProducerInstances" Value="ServiceFabricEtlFile, ServiceFabricPerfCtrFolder" />
      <Parameter Name="MaxDiskQuotaInMB" Value="10240" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ServiceFabricEtlFile">
      <Parameter Name="ProducerType" Value="EtlFileProducer" />
      <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="EtlReadIntervalInMinutes" Value=" 5" />
      <Parameter Name="DataDeletionAgeInDays" Value="3" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ServiceFabricPerfCtrFolder">
      <Parameter Name="ProducerType" Value="FolderProducer" />
      <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="FolderType" Value="ServiceFabricPerformanceCounters" />
      <Parameter Name="DataDeletionAgeInDays" Value="3" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="TransactionalReplicator">
      <Parameter Name="CheckpointThresholdInMB" Value="64" />
    </Section>
  </FabricSettings>
</ClusterManifest>
```

Comment: I guess the problem is in `IPAddressOrFQDN="localhost"`. Try to change it  to remote machine's IP address or better to FQDN.

Comment: @cassandrad You are correct. I will post full steps I needed to take to make it all work with remote connections, as there were some subtle other issues, but this was the biggest thing, strangely enough. Please post this as an answer, and I will give it to you as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks, you can mark your own answer as accepted as it is better than mine.

Comment: @cassandrad No I insist, you spotted the underlying problem. I just had other, smaller more trivial issues to deal with after that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why isn't it working?

It is not working because you set IP address of your nodes as `localhost` thus making them undiscoverable. It will work for local debug cluster, but for on-premises and for Azure clusters you have to specify valid and reachable IP address or qualified name.

Also, I'm not 100% sure right now, but I can suggest to specify FQDN instead of IP address if you want your cluster be accessible by URI and not by IP. I remember I had troubles with this, but it is still not clear what has helped — FQDN or something else.

Answer (score 5):

There were a few issues, but the biggest, as @cassandrad mentioned, was that the default deployment binds to the TCP FQDN of localhost (`IPAddressOrFQDN="localhost"`) and not the IP address of the machine, so it only allows local connections by default.

Here are complete steps for fixing my issue:

- I first ran `netstat -a | FindStr "19000"` in Command Prompt to check what bindings were active, in order to affirm what @cassandrad said.
- Reading [this guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/), I decided to download the [Service Fabric standalone package for Windows Server](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=730690) (works just fine outside of Windows Server, on Windows 8.1 x64 by the way).
- I copied and then modified `ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json`, under the `nodes` section I changed all nodes' `iPAddress` to be `192.168.1.102`. I called the new file `ClusterConfig.Unsecure.CustomDevCluster.json`.
- I ran `CreateServiceFabricCluster.ps1`. It asked me what JSON configuration to use, so I gave it `ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json`.
- The first time it failed because of an error fetching `Newtonsoft.JSON` version `6.0.0.0`, as visible from the traces, which was a rather annoying, obfuscated error. The error was because I did not have .NET Framework 4.6.2, so I [downloaded](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344) and installed it.
- The second time it failed because a `Microsoft Azure Service Fabric` MSI was installed. This error came up because I had previously installed [`MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK.exe`](http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK). I went to Programs and Features and uninstalled `Microsoft Azure Service Fabric` (I left the `Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK` installed).
- I ran the script one last time, fingers crossed, it finally worked.
- It is an unsecure cluster, so I was able to simply connect to it using `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster "192.168.1.102:19000"`. If you want to enable other authentication mechanisms, modify and use some of the other `.json` sample configurations.

Comment: How did you choose the ip "192.168.1.102"? I want to connect to my cluster from a remote pc over internet. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192846/cant-publish-to-service-fabric-local-cluster-on-another-machine?rq=1), the IP should be set to external ip, which I looked up on "whatismyip.com". But during cluster creation I get the error message "Machine '94.xxx.xxx.xx' is not reachable on port 445." All ports on local machine are opened.